# Post array of multipart files using HTTP package with same field name, i.e. as form data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send multiple file in the following JSON format;

```
{
  "product_id": 1,
  "images":[ /* here is the array of images picked */ ]
}
```

Using dio, there is a way to achieve this by form data

```
FormData.fromMap({
 "product_id":product_id,
 'images': [
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync('./example/upload.txt', filename: 'upload.txt'),
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync('./example/upload.txt', filename: 'upload.txt'),
 ]
});
```

How can I achieve this using HTTP package?

```
List<http.MultipartFile> _multiFiles = [];

  images.forEach((element) async {
    final _part = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      "images",
      element,
      contentType: MediaType('application', '*'),
    );
    _multiFiles.add(_part);
  });


 final _request = http.MultipartRequest(
    'POST',
    _appUrl(_url),
  )..fields['product_id'] = product.id.toString()
   ..files.addAll(_multipartFiles)
```

Using this, the images are not uploaded since the backend requires key named "images", which is an array of files,how do I achieve this.

Comment: what is the problem of using http? can you provide an example?

Comment: have edited the question, check my example